# Product development questions

Tags: discussion

There is a [post today](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34955/innovative-rain-pants) that seems over the line for an ad to me (I voted to close), but it also seems reasonable for people or companies developing bicycle related technologies and gear to want feedback. Do we have clear guidance about appropriate ways to ask those questions? I didn't find anything…

For example:

"We've got a cool product on Kick Starter, take a look and give us feedback" seems to be just on the wrong side of the line to me.

However:

"We've got an idea for a product (possibly with a link to a website) and would like to know what features matter to you" seems like it would be ok.

The difference, as I see it, is that the second version asks (or could be asking) a general and keeps the discussion on SE. The first version takes the discussion away and asks for a response to a specific product.

Comment: I think a survey post (if we allow them) should be made a wiki post. In my understanding, a wiki is meant for cases where there can be multiple, equally correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that survey questions are explicitly not appropriate. SE also discourages opinion-only questions. And just as a matter of terminology, this is a question-and-answer site, so that is supposedly a question not a post. So it's hard to see how those questions could fit within the existing rules.

The only way one could fit would be as a blog post, I think. We might have to advertise that somehow, or just delete the question and email the asker to say "submit a blog post". That would allow proper exposition of the idea and a link to a survey on another site.